# BP (maybe EP too) word/expression basically meaning "really busy" or "having no free time"

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, palavra-para-ideia

I'm thinking of a specific one, something to do with *correira*, or *corrida* or something...  That's kind of vague, but I know there is a an expression that I've heard and used before, but I can't put my finger on what it is.

The reason I'm asking this question, is because I nearly said:

> Nossa, tô muito correio no momento

in a facebook message with a friend the other day, and then I re-read it before sending and thought, “no, I am not a post office.  That's definitely not the word I am looking for...”

Comment: "correria desenfreada"?

Comment: @Centaurus, could you leave the original *correira*? It's the object of the question. I answered on the basis of it, and my answered was accepted already.

Comment: @Jacinto    The OP says it was a typo, not a mistake.  That's why I fixed it:   **Just one detail: it's "correria", not "correira" (note the position of "i")** – Hugo  ---   **Goddammit, I have no idea why I typed it that way, I've already learnt this! haha** – Some_Guy    See in the comments below.

Comment: Well, Some-Guy, I think we should leave this to you. I answered on the basis that you didn't remember the right word (hence, the *correio* too); otherwise I can just change my opening sentence to "yes, it is *correria*". @Centaurus note Some_Guy typed *correira* again in that exchange you quote from (second comment to Hugo's answer), after reading *correria* in my answer.

Comment: @Jacinto No início errei no questão porque não sabia mesmo.  Depois, li a tua resposta, e aprendi a palavra certa.  E daí, falando com o Hugo, mesmo que nesse ponto já tinha sabido que a palavra é *correria*, eu fiz o mesmo erro (mas esse vez como um "typo").  Não é simples mas é o que aconteceu kkkkk  Faz sentido que não ficou claro

Comment: Apoio deixar esse erro no questão, porque no início realmente não sabia que a palavra que eu estava procurando é "correria"

Comment: É normalmente isso que nós fazemos: deixamos o erro na pergunta e explicamos na resposta (exceto erros que não têm que ver com o ponto da pergunta).

Comment: YAY YOU ALL UNDERSTOOD ME WOOOOOOO.  Sorry.  I know we're not meant to have fun on stackexchange.  I'll stop now.  I don't want to get in trouble with the people over at ELU.

Comment: Dois pesos e duas medidas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be thinking of [*correria* (Aulete):](http://www.aulete.com.br/correria)

> **2.** Pressa, agitação; CORRE-CORRE; LUFA-LUFA: *a correria das pessoas no centro da cidade* [Antôn.: lentidão, vagar.]

If you say “ando numa correria” or “estou numa correria” you mean you have many things to do and little time to do it; so you’re really busy and have no free time. It is a common word in Portugal, and it is in use in Brazil too. Here are some examples (emphasis mine):

> Minha gente, sei que ando meio sumida aqui do blog, mas é que **estou numa correria danada!** Isto porque além de gravar os programas, tocar a loja, dar umas aulas em faculdades, ainda estou organizando [...]   [(Ana Carina blog, 2015)](http://www.annacorinna.com.br/blog/post/correria_correria_estaremos_na_casar)
>
> Galera, **estamos numa correria danada** dando os últimos ajustes sobre uma novidade [(Facebook.)](https://www.facebook.com/DucaTambascoG3/posts/229293777119661)
>
> Chico Bento resolve fazer alguns bicos para reforçar o seu orçamento e assim ajudar os pais com a faculdade, o que transforma sua vida **numa correria entre quatro empregos**.  [(UpStage.)](http://livrariaupstage.com/historias-em-quadrinhos/chico-bento-moco-no-6-mudancas.html)

You can also say with the same meaning, *ando num [corre-corre](http://www.aulete.com.br/corre-corre)* (Aulete 3), *ando numa [roda-viva](http://www.aulete.com.br/roda-viva)* (Aulete), or *ando numa [lufa-lufa](http://www.aulete.com.br/lufa-lufa)* (Aulete).

There is a somewhat related phrase: [***às carreiras***, which means ‘in a hurry’ (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=carreira). But you don’t usually say “estou às carreiras;” It is usually used with “fazer alguma coisa”: if you do something ‘às carreiras’ you do it in hurry:

> “A nossa proposta é que seja feito um planejamento visando a **reposição sem pressa**, pois deve-se priorizar a qualidade do ensino. Não é porque aceitamos a proposta do Governo que iremos **fazer tudo ‘às carreiras’** ” [(Diário do Nordeste, 2016.)](http://diariodonordeste.verdesmares.com.br/cadernos/cidade/professores-da-uece-suspendem-a-greve-apos-172-dias-1.1638187)
>
> Por aqui só estamos de passagem...E é passagem curta. Tudo muito breve, **tudo às carreiras**, não há tempo para o desperdício... [(Facebook, 2016.)](https://www.facebook.com/SimplesAssimD/photos/a.1439585509662562.1073741828.1439582742996172/1770536599900783/?type=3&theater)

Comment: Perfeito.  No correiro nem tô!  Errei pois estou numa correria essas semãnas então tô meio doido sabe ;)

Comment: What ways of qualifying it might there be?  I see that guy using "danada" (damn?).  Would muito or realmente work with this construction, and are there other words that could be commonly used to qualify it? (por exemplo correira grande, correira intensa, sei lá...)

Comment: @Some_Guy, yes, I know of no corresponding adjective. So you have to say "estou/tou/tô numa correria". In Portugal we tend to say "ando..."

Comment: @Some_Guy You could say, "correria danada/louca/doida/estonteante". Yes, *danada* means *damned*, but it's being used as an intensifier.

Comment: To what where you referring in your first comment there when you said "yes"?

Comment: @Some_Guy, Oh, I was expressing agreemente with "nem correiro nem tô" in your first comment. (You can say *tô numa correria* but not just *tô correria*.)

Comment: ah, I see.  well I meant to say "no correio nem tô" as in "I'm not at the post office" haha, anyway, thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @Some_Guy My bad, I misread it.

Comment: I miswrote it too!

Comment: @Some_Guy There's a related phrase, *às carreiras*, which I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing [@Jacinto's answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/4414/1798) and also answering your question in [this comment](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/bp-maybe-ep-too-word-expression-basically-meaning-really-busy-or-having-no#comment-11650).

The word you're looking for is **correria** and it's used as a noun (so you can't combine it with words like **muito** or **realmente**).

If you want to emphasize or intensify it, you could add words like **danada**. When you say **correria danada**, the word **danada** in this case means something like "very big", "very intense". So in this sentence:

> Estou numa correria danada

The word **danada** is emphasizing how big/intense is my "correria" - I'm really busy and with lots and lots of things to do, and have a very short time to finish them.

*Although "danada" is related to "damn", I believe in this case it's not used with the same meaning. But I might be wrong...*

You could also use other words instead of **danada**, with equivalent meanings:

> Estou numa correria doida/desgraçada/maluca/intensa/foda

To combine with **muito** or **realmente**, you could use the corresponding adjective **corrido** (masculine) or **corrida** (feminine):

> Minha vida está muito corrida (My life is very "corrida" - it means I'm in the middle of a "correria" situation at this moment)
>
> Minha vida está realmente corrida (My life is really "corrida" - same thing as above)

It's equivalent to **Estou numa correria**

Another example:

> Foi tudo muito corrido (Things happened very fast)

---

Well, there's an exception:

> Ontem foi muita correria!

In this case, **muita** means **too much**. So this sentence means something like **Yesterday was such a lot of 'correria'!**
You could use it when telling someone how was the "correria" you had yesterday.

> Nossa, tá muita correria! (Wow, that's too much "correria"!)

You could say this when you're in the middle of your "correria" (you're trying to do all the things you have to) as a complaining (that's too much for me) or just as a comment about your situation.

Comment: resposta muita boa!  Valeu mano!!!  Então dá pra dizer "Nossa, tá tudo muito corrido essa semana" por exemplo, né?

Comment: Also, this explains why I had misinterpreted correria as an adjective;  I think I'd heard an expression like "nossa, tá muito correria!" and interpreted it like "wow, it's really correria here!" rather than "wow, this is a lot of correira!", if that makes sense.

Comment: Sim, "Tá tudo muito corrido" é uma frase digna de um falante nativo!

Comment: Just one detail: it's "correria", not "correira" (note the position of "i")

Comment: Goddammit, I have no idea why I typed it that way, I've already learnt this!  haha

Comment: Maybe you are in a "correria" (I usually mistype things when I'm in the middle of one)

Comment: sim estou mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

There are several phrases to convey that you are "really very busy", from slang to very formal Portuguese.

- Estou sem tempo nenhum.
- Estou numa correria danada.
- Estou sobrecarregado.
- Estou mais ocupado do que nunca.
- Cara, não tenho tempo nem pra me coçar.
- Tenho muito o que fazer, e era tudo pra ontem.
- Estou assoberbado de serviço.
- Estou ocupadíssimo no momento.
- Não vou poder ir hoje, tô garrado.
- Meu amigo, eu estou mais ocupado do que banheiro da Oktoberfest.
- Olha, no momento eu estou mais ocupado do que puta em dia de pagamento no quartel.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to ask more slang questions just to read your answers Centaurus.  Ponte que partiu que divertido!